# discontinuity of a absolute value piece wise function

Tags: limits, continuity

So I have this piecewise function here:

$f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \cos(\frac{\pi x}{2}),  & \  \ |x| < 1 \\
            \ |x-1|, &   |x|\geq 1
        \end{array}
    \right.$

I know that I can use the definition of continuity to do this question and find that the definition does not hold at x=1 but the absolute values are throwing me off. How would I exactly deal with that? This would be really easy if the absolute value isn't in the domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: check $ x=+1, -1$.

Comment: I get that at 1, the definition hold and that at -1 it does not hold since the two sided limits do not equal to each other so -1 is a point of discontinuity I believe.

Comment: You are right .

Comment: you'r welcome .